# Calculating Gate Resistor for IRFP260N

Tags: mosfet, resistors

I want to use two IRFP260N for DIY Inverter 12-220V.
I have CD4047 and I want to use it as driver. What resistor value can I put between CD4047 and IRFP260N Gate?

Answer (score 1):

A very good place to start is the test conditions of the part. In this case that is 1.8R-25R (say 10R). This will be a very good and safe place to start as your initial powercore design as the other numbers from teh datasheet (losses etc) will be derived from using this value.

once you have a gatedrive and a powercore designed,  a level of specific checking can be done to retune the gate resistor with respect to switching characteristics.

[what the best way to calculate Rg gate driver for Mosfet](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287792/what-the-best-way-to-calculate-rg-gate-driver-for-mosfet/287805#287805)

Answer (score 1):

A CD4047 has such low output current that no gate resistor is required.