# Gate Driver HCPL3120

Tags: gate-driving

I want to use HCPL3120 gate driver:

Its data sheet is here: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/678/V02-0161EN_DS_HCPL-3120_2016-03-21-908803.pdf

On page number 22 there is an excellent design for IGBT, but I didn't understand how to find the value of Rg. Also, what is the value of the resistor which is attached to the "74xxx open collector"? It is shown as a 270W resistor, which is too high!

---

Additional questions:

On page 23 there is a design process that he followed, but I have some questions:

- what is VOL and IOLpeak?
- from where did he obtain 178mW as a max output power?
- what if my output power is less than the maximum power?
- from where did he obtain bias output power?
- after obtaining Esw, how can I determine how much I should increase from the resistance?

Comment: Ω and W are common  errors due to Unicode fonts when it should be ASCII or ANSI ..ASCII​​ ​​​​ कं ट?ट या ?वषय-व?तु

Answer (score 2):

I think the "270W" marking is a problem with the fonts used in the schematic, and that this resistor should be marked as 270Ω instead. My guess is that a special symbol font was used in the schematic but a font substitution was made when the pdf was created.

The calculation of \$R_g\$ is pretty well described. You should explain specifically what you "don't get" about it.

Comment: first, what is VOL and IOLpeak , from where did he obtain 178 as a max output power , what if my output power is less than the maximum power ,  from where did he obtain bias output power, after obtaining Esw how can I determine how much I should increase from the resistance

Comment: @محمدراشد Don't ask more questions in a comment. Add this to your original question, and specify exactly where in the datasheet you have a question. Don't make us search the datasheet for "178".

Comment: I edited the question please check again

Comment: so you don't have an answer

Comment: I am sorry that the demands of my own life interfered with the time I had available to read the datasheet for you and provide free engineering consultation. I'm sure by now that you have it all sorted out. Best of luck with your project.

Comment: No I didn't get it yet

Answer (score 2):

The 270W is a typo in the datasheet, this should be 270Ω

As to the gate resistor. This would be outside the scope of the gate drive chip because it is heavily influenced by the gate you are driving and under what conditions: The gate capacitance.

To calculate the value (and the wattage) of the resistor, please consider the information in this post: [what the best way to calculate Rg gate driver for Mosfet](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287792/what-the-best-way-to-calculate-rg-gate-driver-for-mosfet/287805#287805)

Identify the device you want to switch, look at the test-case Rg, follow up with sizing calculations

Comment: but I will be using it for IGBT not MOSFET

Comment: that doesn't matter since the concept is exactly the same