# How does a MOSFET gate resistor reduce ringing?

Tags: mosfet

I desiged P-MOSFET for reverse voltage protection, without gate resistor.

The reason that I tend to use it is protect from reverse DC voltage when
someone connects the battery.  Do I need a gate resistor?
(When someone connects the battery correctly it will be in the ON state, otherwise the PMOS will be OFF.)

Second question:

How does a gate resistor reduce ringing?

Comment: Show your schematic design; embed an image so everyone knows exactly what you are talking about. Battery voltage range and output current range values are needed.

Comment: its a simple voltage circuit protection with dc input that could connect from ATX Power supply(12v) its okay for datasheet... @Andyaka

Comment: Does [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68748/question-about-mosfet-gate-resistor) answer your question?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287792/what-the-best-way-to-calculate-rg-gate-driver-for-mosfet/287805#287805